# Gatsby - change over-the-fold initial HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby

I'm building landing pages with the amazing Gatsby framework (version 2.16.1).

Everything would have worked perfectly, except that I can't find a way to make changes to the HTML that's being loaded before any script is loaded (the 'over-the-fold' initial HTML).

For example, if I change the HTML's background color in Gatsby - Users can wait up to 5 seconds since the 'over-the-fold' initial HTML is displayed, until the background color is applied.

I know about `gatsby-browser.js` and the ability to make global CSS files, but that's no use for me as I use a different color or background-picture for each landing page.

My question is: Can I affect the first loaded HTML (differently for each Gatsby page) in Gatsby or React?

Illustration: I color the background color as yellow, but the flow is like this -

```
HTML is first displayed (background=while) -->
3-5 seconds later -->
all scripts are loaded, and background changes to yellow
```

Comment: "I can't find a way to make changes to the HTML that's being loaded before any script is loaded" - what HTML are you talking about?  The index HTML file is just a wrapper for Gatsby scripts, you shouldn't need to set any style here, just set the style in your components.

Comment: "HTML is first displayed (background=while) -->", if you mean "white", then you're misunderstanding what's going on. That white background is not your site, it's just an empty page that shows your site isn't loaded yet. You could try styling `.___gatsby: { background: #f00; }`. That should give you a red background.

Comment: @JMadelaine, I fully understand your comment, however, I cannot accept a landing page that its background image only starts to get loaded after 5 seconds. Isn't there a way to change that wrapper index HTML? Is gatsby not suitable for landing pages (in which such bad performance is the difference between earning money and losing)?

Comment: BTW - thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ksav answered the question in a comment to the question! Thank you!

The answer is using a function called `onRenderBody` under the `gatsby-ssr.js` file, as explained in the article that was mentioned: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

```
exports.onRenderBody = ({setBodyAttributes,pathname,}) => {
  // Differentiate between the landing pages here
  switch(pathname) {
    case 'landing_page_a':
    case 'landing_page_b':
  }

  // Affect the HTML that gets loaded before React here
  setBodyAttributes({
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  });
}
```

The funny thing is, that I've already bumped into this article before, but didn't think it was relevant because it talked about server-side-rendering, and I know that Gatsby is server-less. After @ksav 's comment, I re-read it, and understood that the server-side-rendering happens during Gatsby's build process, and not during run-time (i.e. when the user enters the landing pages).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I affect the first loaded HTML (differently for each Gatsby page) in Gatsby or React?

Yes, you can directly in the JSX React code. Google has [documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) how you can optimize CSS delivery so your above-the-fold content is always styled correctly. It comes down to using inline CSS for all your components above the fold. With inline CSS your HTML elements are always styled when they are loaded because the styling is part of the HTML code.

See the React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) for how to handle inline styles in React.

An example from the Gatsby tutorial:

```js
src/pages/index.js

import React from "react"
export default () => (

  {/* inline CSS */}
  <div style={{ margin: `3rem auto`, maxWidth: 600 }}> 

    <h1>Hi! I'm building a fake Gatsby site as part of a tutorial!</h1>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the flow is: initial HTML gets loaded -> only then Gatsby/React gets loaded. And your answer does improve performance, but doesn't affect the initial HTML, so a delay still occurs until the component's script gets downloaded and starts running.